# Blade nested section produces misformatted DOM

Tags: laravel, dom, laravel-blade

Here is the content of my `home.blade.php` file:

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('content')
  @extends('partials.sidebar')
    @section('pagecontent')
      This is home
    @endsection
@endsection
```

`layouts/master.blade.php` contains the main layout which has the typical `<html><head><body>`structure. In it's `<body>`, I am yielding to a section called `content`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app">
    @yield('content')
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my `parials/sidebar.blade.php`, I am yielding to a section called `pagecontent`:

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            @yield('pagecontent')
        </div>
</div>
```

So I would naturally expect a DOM like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app"> <!-- @section('content') -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            This is home <!-- @section('pagecontent') -->
        </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, that's not the DOM my blade views are rendering. My sidebar partial doesn't get injected inside the master layout, instead, it is appended to the DOM as a sibling of the **Entire Document:**

```
<div id="page-content-wrapper">
   <div class="container-fluid">
       This is home <!-- @section('pagecontent') -->
   </div>
</div>

<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<body>
  <div id="app"> <!-- @section('content') -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can't use [`@extends`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#extending-a-layout) like this. Use [`@include`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#including-sub-views) instead:

```
@include('partials.sidebar')
```

Comment: I have a section (`pagecontent`) in sidebar. The text "This is home" is not being inserted to that section if I change @extends to @include

Comment: Any suggestions?